# ViewPagerIndicator tabs - control over text styling

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I'm using ViewPagerIndicator http://viewpagerindicator.com/

The theme specifies a style, which is being used (I can change the text colour in the style and see it affect the tab text)

```
<style name="TabText" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator.Text">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

I want to control how longer tab names are handled. I want to trial using wrap_content (i.e. so tabs resize to wrap the text width) and I also want to trial using ellipsizing on long text (i.e. tabs all the same width, but if the title is too long, it ellipsizes).

[image]

The ellipsizing works on older devices (e.g. the Nexus One)

[image]

But on ICS the ellipsizing is not working, and the title just truncates

How do I control the width & ellipsizing of tab text in VPI?

(on a related note I find long text by default wraps in VPI, so I'm search-replacing spaces with non-breaking spaces to stop that as singleLine=true in the style causes VPI to throw a cast exception)

Comment: "as singleLine=true in the style causes VPI to throw a cast exception" -- a `TextView` is a `TextView`, regardless of whether it is single line or not. What `ClassCastException` is being thrown?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it, but it was a ClassCastException being thrown from within VPI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution appears to be simple, to add `singleLine=true"` to the style. It seems the truncation was not truncation, but actually wrapping.

Adding this attribute no longer causes a cast exception in VPI in my project, so I can only assume some other factor was involved in the cast exception I was seeing previously.